# image shows in html but is broken in nginx

Tags: html, nginx

nginx comes with a default html that shows Welcome to nginx! message.

I modified this default html by adding an image to it.

When I open the modified html, the image shows as expected.

When I open 0.0.0.0, the usual Welcome to nginx! shows but the image is broken (it shows as an icon!). How can I allow nginx to show the image in the html?

Thanks a lot

Comment: hello here is the answer! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74673908/nginx-cant-show-the-image-in-html/74710806#74710806

Comment: hello here is the answer! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74673908/nginx-cant-show-the-image-in-html/74710806#74710806

Comment: Monsanto hello, here is the answer! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74673908/nginx-cant-show-the-image-in-html/74710806#74710806

Answer (score 2):

You can create an images folder inside html, like this:

```
usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.15.8/html/images
```

Then copy your image to this place and in the html file change your image src to:

```
images/file.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find out all nginx error logs at this location:

```
/var/log/nginx/
```

You can then open the error.log file with vim:

```
vim error.log
```

nginx record all error logs at error.log. You can also check out the access.log file. This file record information about all access requests.

```
vim access.log
```

Comment: Hi Carlos, I am using mac and I don't have /var/log/nginx/ folder. I am not quite sure whether this is an error or whether I need to modify the configurations. As I mentioned, the html file shows the image as expected indicating nothing is wrong with the syntax or with the path of the image. The image is only broken if the html is served by nginx! It is strange because the rest of the html is shown as expected, it is just the image!

Comment: Hi mansanto, you can try find the error log file with the find command in the terminal , like this: find -name error.log.

Comment: I did that but I don't have an error.log file on my system.

Comment: You can also check the default.conf file of nginx to find about where your log path are located.

Comment: Is your html file located at this path: /usr/share/nginx/html? Where is your image located?

Comment: The html file is in: /usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.15.8/html

Comment: The image file is on the desktop

Comment: You can create an images folder inside html.  usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.15.8/html/images. Then copy your image to this place and in the html file change your image src to images/file.jpg

Comment: That took care of, if you would like to change your answer to this solution, I'll vote it up as a correct answer. Thanks a lot, I appreciate it.

Comment: Sure! Glad i could help!