# nginx cant show the image in html

Tags: html, css, image, nginx, web

I am new to working with "Nginx" and I want to display an image as the website background but the image does not show and I get a 403 error for the image.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
        <meta http-equiv="refresh"content="10">
    </head>
    <body>
        Nothing
    </body>
</html>
```

styles.css:

```
body {
    background-color:   rgb(29, 49, 53);
    background-image:   url(F.png);
}
```

nginx.conf:

```
http{
    include mime.types;
    server{
        listen 80;
        root /home/user/mysite;
        location /404.jpeg {}
        location /502.jpeg {}
        location /503.jpeg {}
        location /F.png{}
    }
}

events{}
```

here is the HTML file:

[image]

but in Nginx!:

[image]

and here is the logs of Nginx:

[image]

I want to display an image as the
background of HTML file in Nginx

Comment: What url is being requested, does the file exist, what errors are in the nginx log etc. turning on [nginx debug logs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/debugging_log.html) will likely self answer your question - but if it doesn’t, putting those log messages in the question would be useful. Please edit the question to address comments

Comment: it says permission denied I changed the directory to /var/www/mysite but still the same. here is the last log ```2022/12/06 11:55:39 [error] 16772#16772: *11 open() "/var/www/mysite/A.jpeg" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET /A.jpeg HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080", referrer: "http://localhost:8080/"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I found the problem!!!
somehow we must make the image file executable using the bellow command then Nginx can serve it correctly.

```
chmod 755 F.png
```

I hope it will be useful for others too.